# what is my appID on developer.paypal

Tags: android, paypal

I want to create a PayPal functionality on android. I have created a  test sandbox account at developer.paypal.com

I want to use this function in my coding:

```
PayPal pp = **PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "what should I write here",PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
```

What should I write in second argument? I have that error in project:

> Authentication failed, button not enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution for above question:-

**Paypal pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T",PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);**

i resolved the problem by taking help from some paypal tutorial.

Thanks to all tried to help me...

Comment: Dear Spk, appId APP-80W284485P519543T is fixed for sandbox. Sandbox is trial paypal way. when you will integrate with live server then it will create different appId. If you are using paypal app id only for development then you can use this id in your code. This will work fine for you. or you can read this tutorial :-http://learnandroiddev.blogspot.in/2010/09/paypal-integration-for-android-apps.html

Comment: You know anything about `Mobile Express Checkout Library`

Comment: @Spk may be i am not master mind in Mobile Express Checkout library, but i can handle this alot. I worked on it before 3 months. If you need my help then i always here for your help...

Comment: Do you've gtalk or skype? I want some clarification from you. Shall i add you to my list. If you don't mind, give me anyone of the id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8347/discussion-between-spk-and-pushpendra-kuntal)

Comment: I am in my company and we are not allowed to chat with outside world in working ours. So sorry for this time. we can talk some other time. my skype id is pushpendra.kuntal add me.